# How to convert the Random decrement technique from MATLAB into python and its implementation?

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, signals, signal-processing

I was looking into a technique called Random decrement technique from the following links/articles:

- [How can I use Random Decrement Method to convert a non-stationary
  signal into a decay function using Matlab?](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How-can-I-use-Random-Decrement-Method-to-convert-a-non-stationary-signal-into-a-decay-function-using-Matlab)
- [Random Decrement Technique](https://github.com/zwynne/random-decrement-waves)
- [Using the Random Decrement Method for the Decentralized Acquisition
  of Modal Data](https://kuscholarworks.ku.edu/bitstream/handle/1808/7752/Dande_ku_0099M_11262_DATA_1.pdf;sequence=1)

I found out that this technique was created in MATLAB which can be found in the following link ([Damping ratio estimation from ambient vibrations (SDOF)](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/55557-damping-ratio-estimation-from-ambient-vibrations-sdof)). I tried to convert the code into python using smop, however, I think I made a mistake with the conversion. I feel that I misused smop package and tried recoding the converted file, but, I feel that I might have done something wrong. The code and conversion can be found below:

***MATLAB:***

```
function [R,t] = RDT(y,ys,T,dt)
%
% [R] = RDT(y,ys,T,dt) returns the free-decay response (R) by
% using the random decrement technique (RDT) to the time serie y, with a
% triggering value ys, and for a duration T
%
% INPUT:
%   y: time series of ambient vibrations: vector of size [1xN]
%   dt : Time step
%   ys: triggering values (ys < max(abs(y)) and here ys~=0)
%   T: Duration of subsegments (T<dt*(numel(y)-1))
% OUTPUT:
%   R: impusle response function
%   t: time vector asociated to R
% 
% Author: E. Cheynet - UiB - last modified 14-05-2020
%%
if T>=dt*(numel(y)-1)
    error('Error: subsegment length is too large');
else
    % number of time step per block
    nT = round(T/dt); % sec
end
if ys==0
    error('Error: ys must be different from zero')
elseif or(ys >=max(y),ys <=min(y)),
    error('Error:  ys must verifiy : min(y) < ys < max(y)')
else
    % find triggering value
    ind=find(diff(y(1:end-nT)>ys)~=0)+1;
    
end
% construction of decay vibration
R = zeros(numel(ind),nT);
for ii=1:numel(ind)
    R(ii,:)=y(ind(ii):ind(ii)+nT-1);
end
% averaging to remove the random part
R = mean(R);
% normalize the R
R = R./R(1);
% time vector corresponding to the R
t = linspace(0,T,numel(R));
end

coeff = 5; % interpolation coefficient
newDT = median(diff(interp(t,coeff)));
newY = interp(y,coeff);
% triggering value
ys = max(abs(y))/5;
% subsegment duration
Ts = round(t(end)/30);

% RDT function
[IRF,newT] = RDT(newY,ys,Ts,newDT);
% get the envelop of the curve with the hilbert transform:
envelop = abs(hilbert(IRF));
envelop(1)=IRF(1);
clf;close all;
figure
hold on; box on;
plot(newT,IRF,'b',newT,envelop,'k');
xlabel('time (s)')
ylabel('normalized displacement')
xlim([0,Ts])
set(gcf,'color','w')
% fit an exponential decay to the envelop
optionPlot = 1;
wn = 2*pi*0.2; % -> obtained with peak picking method (fast way)
[zeta] = expoFit(envelop,newT,wn,optionPlot);
legend('IRF','envelop',' best fit')
```

***Python:***

```
# Generated with SMOP  0.41
# from libsmop import *
# RDT.m

from scipy.signal import chirp, spectrogram
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

    
# @function
def RDT(y=None,ys=None,T=None,dt=None,*args,**kwargs):
    # varargin = RDT.varargin
    # nargin = RDT.nargin

    
    # [R] = RDT(y,ys,T,dt) returns the free-decay response (R) by
# using the random decrement technique (RDT) to the time series y, with a
# triggering value ys, and for a duration T
    
    # INPUT:
#   y: time series of ambient vibrations: vector of size [1xN]
#   dt : Time step
#   ys: triggering values (ys < max(abs(y)) and here ys~=0)
#   T: Duration of subsegments (T<dt*(np.size(y)-1))
# OUTPUT:
#   R: impusle response function
#   t: time vector asociated to R
# 
# Author: E. Cheynet - UiB - last modified 14-05-2020
    
    if T >= np.dot(dt,(np.size(y) - 1)):
        error('Error: subsegment length is too large')
    else:
        # number of time step per block
        nT=round(T / dt)
# RDT.m:22
    
    if ys == 0:
        error('Error: ys must be different from zero')
    else:
        if ys >= max(y) or ys <= min(y):
            error('Error:  ys must verifiy : min(y) < ys < max(y)')
        else:
            # find triggering value
            ind=np.nonzero(np.diff(y(np.arange(1,y[-1] - nT)) > ys) != 0) + 1
# RDT.m:30
    
    # construction of decay vibration
    R=zeros(np.size(ind),nT)
# RDT.m:34
    for ii in np.arange(1,np.size(ind)).reshape(-1):
        R[ii,np.arange()]=y(np.arange(ind(ii),ind(ii) + nT - 1))
# RDT.m:36
    
    # averaging to remove the random part
    R=mean(R)
# RDT.m:39
    # normalize the R
    R=R / R(1)
# RDT.m:41
    # time vector corresponding to the R
    t=np.linspace(0,T,np.size(R))
# RDT.m:43
    return R,t
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = np.linspace(0, 10, 3000)
    w = chirp(t, f0=6, f1=1, t1=10, method='linear')
    plt.plot(t, w)
    plt.title("Linear Chirp, f(0)=6, f(10)=1")
    plt.xlabel('t (sec)')
    plt.show()
    
    N = 3000 # number of time step
    # t = linspace(0,1800,N); # time
    dt = np.median(np.diff(t)) # time step
    fs = 1/dt
    
    coeff = 5 # interpolation coefficient
    newDT = np.median(np.diff(np.interp(coeff, t, w)))
    # newDT = np.median(np.diff(interp1d(t, t, w)))
    newY = np.interp(coeff, t, w)
    # triggering value
    ys = max(abs(w))/5
    # subsegment duration
    Ts = round(t[-1]/30)
    
    R, t = RDT(newY,ys,Ts,newDT)
    
    pass
```

I want to obtain a function for RDT and fit the decreasing decrement using an envelope to make sure that it follows decreasing /impulse signal. What could be my mistake here and obtain a reasonable impulse signal? An equation for RD can be found in the following article and photo. ([Design of a Random Decrement Method Based Structural Health Monitoring System](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/274948642_Design_of_a_Random_Decrement_Method_Based_Structural_Health_Monitoring_System))

[image]

I want to implement the function onto for instance signals similar to the ones in the photo below.

[image]

The errors I am getting:

```
ind=np.nonzero(np.diff(y(np.arange(1,y[-1] - nT)) > ys) != 0) + 1
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable


newDT = np.median(np.diff(np.interp(coeff, t, w)))
raise ValueError("diff requires input that is at least one dimensional")
ValueError: diff requires input that is at least one dimensional
```

Also, I’m mainly stuck at this line:

Python:

```
            # find triggering value
            ind=np.nonzero(np.diff(y(np.arange(1,y[-1] - nT)) > ys) != 0) + 1
```

MATLAB:

```
    % find triggering value
    ind=find(diff(y(1:end-nT)>ys)~=0)+1;
```

So, how would I convert this line for the find in MATLAB to python code?

Comment: As it stands, it's unclear what your problem is you think you have made a mistake, but why do you think that? Are the results incorrect, does it error out, ...? Please [edit] the question to clarify.

Comment: @Adriaan I clarified the questiion. See edited version.

Comment: `ind=np.nonzero(np.diff(y(np.arange(1,y[-1] - nT)) > ys) != 0) + 1` you used wrong parenthesis when getting `y` indices. Check `ind=np.nonzero(np.diff(y[np.arange(1,y[-1] - nT)] > ys) != 0) + 1`

Comment: @dankal444 I changed the parentheses and I got following error:” array used as indices must be of integer (or Boolean) type”

Comment: you need to create integer indices `np.arange(1,y[-1] - nT, dtype=np.int64)` instead of float (`np.arange` generates float by default)

Comment: @dankal444, `arange` does produce integers - the inputs are integers.  I don't know what `y[-1] - nT` is.

Comment: @hpaulj yes, integers *if* inputs are integers, but if only one input is float it will produce float

Comment: @dankal444 now I got an error saying:”can only concatenate triple (not “int”) to tuple”

Comment: @hpaulj I included the equation with original code in MATLAB into the question. See edited version